# How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT and Text on Oracle 10g?

Tags: forms, plsql, oracle10g, sequence, auto-increment

Currently have a sequence and trigger set up, i'd like to add text before the auto incremented number i.e when i insert a new record the number appears by itself, i'd like to have a set text for my ids and the only variable as the auto increment.

Create SEQUENCE Student_sequence

```
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;
```

TRIGGER CODE:

```
clear_form;
SELECT Student_sequence.NEXTVAL
INTO :Students.StudentID
FROM DUAL;
```

anyway to get "STU" In-front of the auto incremented number?

Answer (score 0):

As long as students.studentID is a Character field and not a number then the below should work.

```
SELECT 'STU' || Student_sequence.NEXTVAL
INTO :Students.StudentID
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Great thank you, ended up having to declare new variable to hold the number then covert the number increment into char to display text together.